# Can't quite get a simple HTTP server to work on python and get requests from node

Tags: python, node.js, http, request

So I'm just trying to get a GET request to go through from a node.js app to a python app and for some reason the code works when I'm running it in a Jupyter Notebook but not otherwise.
Here's the Python code.

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler , HTTPServer

class HTTPServer_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        print('got a request')

server_address = ('localhost', 9000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, HTTPServer_RequestHandler)
print('running server...')
httpd.serve_forever()
```

and here's the node code

```
var request = require('request');
request.get({
    uri: 'http://localhost:9000',
    type:'GET '
}, function(res,err,body){
  console.log(res)
  console.log(err)
  console.log(body)
});
```

This of course prints an error on the node side, but the interesting thing is that on Jupyter Notebook I get "running server..." output and I also get the "got a request" whenever I run the node, however when I run Python normally I don't get any output at all.

Comment: What error is coming back from the Python server ? what status code ?

Comment: For me the code works in normal Python.